# Error in Python 3.4 (Spyder) while plotting on Open Mandriva

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I was trying to plot an IR spectrum from csv file, like this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file=open('261.1_2014-12-10t16-33-55.csv')
for line in file :
    data.append(line)
    pointset=data[6:]
    for point in pointset:
        res=point.split(',')
        h=float(res[0])
        wn.append(h)
        y=float(res[1])
        Ads.append(y)
plt.plot(wn,Ads)
plt.show()
```

but instead of single line, i get huge lot of them. 
variables Ads and wn have much more entries then point set and data. 
What is wrong?

Comment: What is the shape of `wn` and `Ads`?  They should lists of floats which will get converted to `(N, )` shaped arrays.

Comment: Thank you for edit! They were lists of float. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the lines in the file twice.  For each line in the file, you iterate over each point in pointset, but pointset is just the set of all lines read so far except the first six.

I think this is what you want:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

file = open('filename.csv')

for ii,line in enumerate(file):
    if ii>=6: #skip lines 0, 1,2,3,4,5
        fields = line.split(",")
        wn.append(float(fields[0]))
        Ads.append(float(fields[1]))
plt.plot(wn,Ads)
plt.show()
```